# Thread Safe Control - Crashing VS 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, custom-controls

I am working on creating a thread safe control for my windows forms application.

I understand I can set the text on a control thread safe by using the following code:

```
private delegate void SetTextD(Control control, string value);

private static void SetText(Control control, string value)
{
    if(control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(new SetTextD(SetText), new object[] {control, value});
    }
    else
    {
        control.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then in my form code i can call:

```
SetText(lblStatus, "Updating...");
```

My goal is to create a custom control, which inherits Label. Then inside this class, on the Text property I can just call:

lblStatus.Text = "Updating..."

Then it will automatically do the proper thread safe code.

Here is the code that I have in my class:

```
public class ThreadSafeLabel : Label 
{
    private delegate string GetTextD();
    private delegate void SetTextD(string value);

    private string GetText()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (string)Invoke(new GetTextD(GetText));
        }
        return Text;
    }

    private void SetText(string value)
    {
        if(InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new SetTextD(SetText), new object[] {value});
        }
        else
        {
            Text = value;
        }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return GetText();
        }
        set
        {
            SetText(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I attempt to add this control to my form, it crashes VS 2008. I was thinking that maybe it had to do with setting the initial text property when you add it to the form, but not sure.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or what I might be missing?

If something is not clear, please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A2E0F92) (0)

Comment: I upvoted you.  You probably weren't accepted because I provided a shorter implementation, and, IMHO, a clearer explanation.

Comment: @tanscius sorry but I agree with Slaks, his answer was clearer. It is not always the code that gives the correct answer but the why. - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of C# 3.0's anonymous methods, you don't need separate set and get methods.  The simplest way to do what you're looking for is like this:

```
public class ThreadSafeLabel : Label {
    public override string Text {
        get {
            return InvokeRequired ? Invoke(new Func<string>(() => base.Text)) : base.Text;
        }
        set { 
            if (InvokeRequired)
                BeginInvoke(new Action(() => base.Text = value));
            else
                base.Text = value;
        }
}
```

Note that I'm using `BeginInvoke` so that the calling thread will not wait for the invoke to complete; you might want to change it to `Invoke`.

**EDIT**:

The problem with your code is that your set and get methods are calling your overridden `Text` property again, creating an infinte loop that results in a stack overlow (the exception, not the website).  You need to write `base.Text` to call the base class' implementation of the `Text` property.

Comment: Yes, the point is to use base.Text ... after that he can refactor the code to work without delegates.

Answer (score 2):

Try a

```
return base.Text;
```

or you will run into a endless loop (when you add the Label to your Form the Text-property is queried - and the endless loop makes VS crash). Same for your setter.